# Using solr graph to traverse N relationships

Tags: graph, solr, stream

I'm investigating if I can use an existing solr store to do graph traversal. It would be ideal to not have to duplicate the data in a graph store. I was playing with the solr streaming capabilities and the nodes (gatherNodes) source. I have three problems with it and I'm wondering if people have found solutions:

1) getting the original documents that the nodes references with all of their fields. I did eventually solve this by doing an innerJoin on the nodes returned by gatherNodes and a query against "*:*" but this seem less than ideal. Is there a better way to do this? Even better would be if I could do it as an "export" and not a "select" to better handle large amounts of data. This problem is small compared to the other two which seem like major bugs in Solr

2) I can't traverse to nodes from a field that has more than one value.  In the nodes stream source definition there is a walk parameter.

```
nodes(collection,
search(some search params)
walk="ref->id",
gather="vals")
```

in this example its walking the from the search results, taking the field "ref" on those docs and finding all nodes that match that as an id. This works until ref becomes a list of values. Has anyone had success making this work? A simple example would be a tree structure where you have a folder document and it has a multiValue field representing its subfolders and files. How would I walk that relationship?

3) in that example the gather is returning the nodes that are represented by the "vals" field on all the nodes that result from the walk. This also does not work if that field is multiValued. Has anyone had any success with this also? Again going back to the files and folders example, I want to return all the files in the subfolders of the selected folder.

```
nodes(collection,
search(collection, q="path:currentFolder", qt="/select", sort="fileId ASC"),
walk="contents->fileId",
gather="contents",
fq="type:file")
```

I made this up so there may be some typos but the premise is that contents are a multiValued string field and every document, either of type "file" or "folder" has a fileId, which is what the contents field references. How would I accomplish this? Do these fields need to be indexed in a special way?

Also I realize there are probably other ways to perform this query with solr. This is just an example of using graph traversal.

Thanks! I'm really struggling. There's not a lot of examples out about this even though its been around since solr 6.0.

Comment: Something that interesting is I see in the solr documentation it does support a multi valued walk but only if its a hard coded value
`nodes(emails,
      walk="johndoe@apache.org, janesmith@apache.org->from",
      gather="to")`
but when using a different stream as the input of the nodes function it can't resolve fields that are multivalues. It can't even properly resolve text fields that mimic the example above. If I store a field called refs with a value of ref-1, ref-2, ref-3, the only match will be on ref-1 when walk="refs->id"

Comment: I strongly suggest asking this on the solr-user mailinglist as Joel Bernstein (the author) is probably the best person to answer these questions in detail - the graph walking functionality is still fairly new. There might be talks about the feature from previous Lucene Solr Revolutions or this year's Activate though, so check them out to see if they discuss this (Joel has usually been present as far as I remember).

Comment: Also I think the `select` call is just the naming in the streaming expression, the `/export` handler is still used behind the scenes - you should be able to confirm this by looking at the logs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that also. and if I get an answer somewhere else I'll post it here. I have a feeling its just plain not supported though. There's a jira task similar to this :'(

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: No. The solution to multi valued references was to use cross product which got absurd as soon as you needed to build semantic queries with more than just a couple steps or you wanted to gather nodes based on a variable walk length. So we went with a separate graph store.